# How to use Pillow with Django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-models, python-imaging-library

I installed [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) and now want to use it on my Django site to allow uploading of images of through my admin page. See previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079105/uploading-an-image-through-admin-in-django).

What changes do I need to make in my settings file or elsewhere for Django to recognize Pillow and to allow the ImageField to upload the image properly?

Comment: thanks for that pillow info because I know now why my boss not use PIL because he use pillow than PIL

Comment: As I've noticed here in my codes as long as you pip install pillow you don't have to change your settings file or elsewhere. You can now allow to upload images

Comment: @catherine i didn't install it using pip, i just installed it by running python setup.py install from the download at the above link

Comment: that's ok as long as you successfully install it. Try run "pip freeze", see if pillow is there. If there is you can now start for that images

Comment: @catherine I don't have pip installed

Comment: It's better to have pip. But If that's the case try start testing uploading images if it's working

Comment: @catherine When I try to upload an image i get the following error: No module named Image

Comment: I would highly recommend getting intimately familiar with pip, virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper

Comment: @Brandon I have just installed pip and verified that Pillow is installed using the pip freeze command.  So why am i still getting the\at error?

Comment: Did you install Pillow into your system site-packages? or into a virtualenv's site-packages?

Comment: @Brandon in system site-packages.  not using virtualenv

Comment: And other modules load that are also in the system site-packages?

Comment: @Brandon I'm not sure, I don't think so...

Comment: If you can't import other modules in site-packages, then your problem isn't related to Pillow/PIL

Comment: @Brandon how can I check if I can import a module from site-packages?  By running pip freeze i see i have pyOpenSSL installed.  How can in try importing this?

Comment: Do you have django installed in site-packages? If so, just start up Python in a console and type: import django. If it fails, you have an issue.

Comment: @Brandon that import fails... Should I install Django in that location using pip install Django?

Comment: No offense, but it sounds like you need to get a basic understanding of Python and Django to go any further. Configuring a development environment for Python isn't terribly difficult. I would suggest starting with http://djangobook.com/

Comment: @Brandon I think i have it fixed up, now when I can succesfully import django and PIL from the python command line and they are installed in "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages", but when I try to upload the image through admin, I still get an error saying "No module named Image"

Comment: Man, I have no idea. If you can import PIL, it should work in Django.

Comment: Not a fan of the title of this question. It keeps coming up as the top result when searching "django pillow example" and there aren't any examples in the answers below. =(

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that imports now work slightly differently with Pillow vs PIL. The differences are described here: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/porting-pil-to-pillow.html

Django has also now been changed to prefer Pillow over PIL, via this ticket (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19934)

This commit is present in the new Django 1.6a1 release, so the new behaviour will be present in the Django 1.6 release. For now, however, it appears that you can use a new library (initially released May 20, 2013) called Pillow-PIL which will provide a compatibility layer. This can be easily installed with pip via: `pip install --pre Pillow-PIL`

Comment: I'm on Django 1.5.1 and using buildout. This worked like a charm, now all my images know how big they are. Thank You

Comment: I'm trying to do the Tango with Django tutorial, which uses django 1.5. I'm using virtualenvwrapper. I installed Pillow with pip.  pip freeze shows: Django==1.5.5 Pillow==2.4.0 South==0.8.4 wsgiref==0.1.2.  However, in chapter 8, I get the following error: (tangowithdjango)~/dev_django_projects/tangowithdjango$ ./manage.py syncdb *CommandError: One or more models did not validate: rango.userprofile: "picture": To use ImageFields, you need to install the Python Imaging Library...

Comment: @7stud If you are using Django 1.5.5, you are going to need to install Pillow-PIL still (pip install Pillow-PIL). If you want to eliminate this dependency, then upgrade to Django 1.6.x or the upcoming 1.7 release.

Answer (score 6):

First, install pillow (having virtualenv activated preferably) with:

```
pip install pillow
```

You should import it in Django project:

```
from PIL import Image
```

After that you don't need to change settings or anything else. All the modules should work.

Answer (score 3):

In a Python module that makes a drawing I simply put the following.

```
import PIL.Image as Image
```

and likewise for ImageDraw and ImageFont. Those were the only changes that were necessary after a routine PIP installation.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to make any changes in your settings.py or otherwise to use Pillow instead of PIL. Its a drop-in replacement, and simply has to be available on your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I don't have my settings.py file configured for PIL... so how would I do that?

Comment: You don't have to make any settings changes at all. It simply has to be available on the PYTHONPATH. I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: how do i make sure it is available on PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Good question. It depends on whether or not you're using virtualenv, which if you're not, you should.