# Can't install Python Imaging Library using pip

Tags: python, pip

When trying to install Python Imaging Library(PIL) using PIP, the installation failed with the following error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
File "/tmp/pip_build_root/pil/setup.py", line 182
print "--- using Tcl/Tk libraries at", TCL_ROOT
```

[Somebody](https://github.com/mbi/django-simple-captcha/issues/28#issuecomment-14169250) else faced the same issue but the provided solution was for a different library and didn't work for me. In the official mailing list there's an old entry(2003) which discusses the problem but instead of providing a solution, asked to downgrade PIL and providing a fix later (I prefer not to downgrade).

The pip.log file is provided here: http://pastebin.com/YeBLmMBm

Comment: As far as I know, PIL can't be installed with `pip`. That's why alternative `Pillow` exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a new fork of PIL called Pillow which seems to work more consistently than PIL for a lot of people. It's easy to install also. Look [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)(for info/docs) and [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow)(to install). Though I think `pip install Pillow` should work

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to install PIL for ImageField in Django, I found a workaround with Pillow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080121/how-to-use-pillow-with-django).